# Unable to download .eps file programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, eps

I have created a code from which the user is able to download the file. The files which will be downloaded will be used for image files only.

My code is as per below.

```
try
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.Name);
    // replace special characters with blank.
    string filename = GeneralMethods.MakeValidFileName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
    filename += fileInfo.Extension;
    byte[] obj = (byte[])file.OpenBinary();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private);
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + filename);
    Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        Response.BinaryWrite(obj);
    Response.Flush();
   // Response.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{       
}
finally
{

}
```

When I download `.eps` file using this code it cannot open the file in the client application.

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: you have given that line code as `application/postscript` did u double checked it ?

Comment: Yes sir, I checked it. It's the same.

Comment: try giving like this `application/eps` Not sure, but give it a try

Comment: Just as a side-note, your `case`s are equivalent to `Response.ContentType = "image/" + fileInfo.Extension.Remove(0)`.

Comment: Tried the code you suggested but was not helpful.. :-( @NadeemKhan

Comment: How are you returning this? It looks like you are passing this through the browser? In that case this is probably not the best way of doing it. In any case try and add the System.Net.ContentDisposition header to the response object. That has worked for me in the past

Comment: Hello @Bosman, I don't how to accomplish this. Can you provide me the reference link to use ContentDisposition in header?

Comment: Try getting rid of the try/catch block so you can find out about any exceptions. Don't ever hide exceptions from yourself.

Comment: Hello sir, I tried the code by removing the try - catch block. No errors occurred but the file is downloaded corrupted.@JohnSaunders

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this line:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + filename);
```

To look like this:

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = filename,
    Inline = false,
};

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

Adding the Content-Disposition like this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I changed the code as per your suggestion, but did not help

Answer (score 0):

After trying various code tricks finally found an answer.

The only thing I was missing in my code was to define the "Content-Length" header in Response object.

So the code is as per below:

```
try
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.Name);
    string filename = GeneralMethods.MakeValidFileName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
    filename += fileInfo.Extension;
    byte[] obj = (byte[])file.OpenBinary();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Server);
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { FileName = file.Name, Inline=false};
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length",obj.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);                
    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        Response.BinaryWrite(obj);
    Response.Flush();
   // Response.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{       
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
finally
{
}
```

Now it's working in my case...!!! :-).

Hope this helps other too..

Thanks